# How to close parent dialog box from child dialog box which is opened by parent close button click event?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-dialog

I am trying to close a dialog box (parent) from another dialog box (child) which is opened on a parent dialog box close button “X”.

I am able to display a confirm box (with YES, NO buttons) as a child dialog by clicking on the parent dialog box close button “X” event.

I am facing difficulty to close parent dialog box when user click on ‘YES’ button of child dialog box.

Here is my code:

```
ParentDialog = function () {
  $("#fullscreen").dialog({
    title: "Simple Step Wizard",
    position: ["left", "top"],
    width: "100%",
    height: $(window).height(),
    zIndex: 1000,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {$("#left-panel").hide();},
    close: function (event, ui) {                    
      ChildDialog();
    }
  });
}
```

Child Dialog Box:

```
ChildDialog = function () {
  $("#Confirm").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: 'Please Confirm',
    zIndex: 10000,
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 'auto',
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
      Yes: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        //ParentDialog.Close() ??
      },
      No: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
      //$(this).remove();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Indented code properly

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI dialog has got the [`.close()` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close). The example that is written in the documentation is this:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "close" );
```

Adapting this example to your code I can suggest trying out this:

```
ChildDialog = function () {
    $("#Confirm").dialog({
        buttons: {
            Yes: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#fullscreen").dialog("close"); //add this line
            },
            No: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```